# What do I need to develop an Android chat app? On server,on client

Tags: android, architecture, chat

Now I plan to develop an Android chat app, my instructor let me do a
 research first. What else are necessary on my server besides
 Linux+MySQL? And what do I need to do to connect client and server? Do
 I need any APIs? I don't know how to started my project,or I don't
 know the popular architecture for an Android chat app. I will be very
 appreciated if any good guy tell me something about a realizable
 architecture.

Comment: This is not the right place for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to make a chat application.

Personally I would go for using GCM. And use the server primarily for authentication and looking up users.

So my database will hold an user table. With username,password,gcm code, other info to make people search for each other.

Then in my app I would let people log in, then save the gcm code. And build an option where people can look each other up, after they find someone they can register them in their own phone. When registerd you have the GCM code, so you can use GCM to send a message from 1 android device to another.

An example already made can be found here:
http://androidexample.com/GCM/index.php?view=examplecloud&scat=32

Answer (score 0):

- On server: An [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) server
- In client: An [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) client

There are free libraries available for both.